pgAudit Install Not Working Because of Makefile (Postgres 15)
Hi My Makefile supposedly doesnt have an install target. How do I fix this?
I dont understand how it even worked for others.  Also, I cant use an updated version of Postgres due to restrictions at my job, for anyone wondering.
Also, here's the instructions I followed:
Clone the pgAudit extension:
git clone https://github.com/pgaudit/pgaudit.git

Change to pgAudit directory:
cd pgaudit

Checkout REL_15_STABLE branch (note that the stable branch may not exist for unreleased versions of PostgreSQL):
git checkout REL_15_STABLE

Build and install pgAudit:
make install USE_PGXS=1 PG_CONFIG=/usr/pgsql-15/bin/pg_config


This is the error:
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, sh.exe -c "/usr/pgsql-15/bin/pg_config --pgxs", ...) failed.
Makefile:15: pipe: No error
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.

This is my Makefile, which I didnt change from what I found at https://github.com/pgaudit/pgaudit/releases/tag/1.7.0
# contrib/pg_audit/Makefile

MODULE_big = pgaudit
OBJS = pgaudit.o $(WIN32RES)

EXTENSION = pgaudit
DATA = pgaudit--1.7.sql
PGFILEDESC = "pgAudit - An audit logging extension for PostgreSQL"

REGRESS = pgaudit
REGRESS_OPTS = --temp-config=$(top_srcdir)/contrib/pgaudit/pgaudit.conf

ifdef USE_PGXS
PG_CONFIG = pg_config
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
include $(PGXS)
else
subdir = contrib/pgaudit
top_builddir = ../..
include $(top_builddir)/src/Makefile.global
include $(top_srcdir)/contrib/contrib-global.mk
endif

EXTRA_INSTALL += contrib/pg_stat_statements


What happens when you run /usr/pgsql-15/bin/pg_config --pgxs manually? Are you running the commands as the postgres user?

So Im in a Windows Environment  - running that doesn't work. However, "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin\pg_config.exe" --pgxs creates an mk file

Oh Windows... I'm pretty sure it's never been tested on Windows. Perhaps this  can help, but why would you want to run Postgres on Windows in the first place?

I'm limited to using Windows.. Lets just say my job likes to come up with difficult tasks lol. And thanks, I'll take a look

@mustaccio your link was blocked on my phone & laptop for an expired certificate. Is there another place that has similar instructions? I'm currently trying to follow along with the github page that I posted with this question
